Will a transaction without transaction fee be ignored indefinitively and never put in the blockchain?
If I broadcast a transaction of mine, and decide to not put any transaction fee, is there still an incentive for a miner to include it in to the block?
Maybe related to this, when the block itself awarded a large new amount of bitcoins when created, the so-called coinbase, would users even include a transaction fee for their transactions? And if not, then what incentivises the miners to include any transactions? Could they not just produce an empty block and get the coinbase anyway?

Transactions with a fee less than a configured minimum amount are not forwarded by many nodes, such as those based on Bitcoin Core. So such transactions will probably not ever reach a miner unless special arrangements are made directly with a miner.
Occasionally blocks are produced, even now, with no transactions in them other than the coinbase. This can happen, for example, when a miner sees a new block and so restarts mining with an empty template until a parallel process completes assembly of a set of unconfirmed transactions for a new template.
Miners mostly like free money. So they generally are somewhat inclined to also gather fee-paying transactions into their block templates as soon as possible.
They have no incentive to include transactions with zero fees if there are any other transactions they could choose instead.
